# Understanding localizedTitle and localizedDescription in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, in-app-purchase, skproduct

I'm currently implementing the in-app purchase mechanism and there are three things that I don't fully understand.

In the following tableView I'm retrieving the products from the app storm using a singleton class and there are three thing that I'm not sure what they exactly do...

What does `as! SKProduct` do?

What do `localizedTitle` and `localizedDescription` do?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
    // what does `as! SKProduct` do
    let product = IAPManager.sharedInstance.products.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! SKProduct

    // what does localizedTitle do?
    cell.textLabel!.text = product.localizedTitle
    // what does localizedDescription do?
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = product.localizedDescription

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Read the documentation for `SKProduct` to learn what `localizedTitle` and `localizedDescription` are.

Comment: Read the basics of the Swift programming language to understand what `as! SKProduct` means.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction I was looking at the wrong documentation ... https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nserror/1414418-localizeddescription

Answer (score 0):

Thank you `rmaddy` for pointing me in the right direction I was looking at the wrong documentation... https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nserror/1414418-localizeddescription

localizedTitle and localizedDescription:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProduct_Reference/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKProduct/localizedDescription

as:
https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=23

Thanks